# Placement of 〜て of manner in longer sentence (citing NHK Easy)

Tags: translation, て-form, word-order

Reading an [NHK Easy news article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10012658731000/k10012658731000.html) today, I came across the following sentence (emphasis mine):

> 新しいコロナウイルスがうつらない**ように**、**映像を使って**人が集まらない**ようにする**新しい技術を、いろいろな会社が考えています。

Which I have interpreted to mean

> Various companies are coming up with new technologies using images to prevent the spread of novel coronavirus and prevent people from gathering (into groups).

However, my interpretation requires a leap of faith, as I cannot explain why the 〜て phrase (describing *manner of action*) appears between the two 〜ように clauses while applying to both, nor why this is a valid way to join two clauses (eg why not *〜ようにして。。。〜ようにする* or *〜ようにしたり。。。ようにしたりする* or similar).

Is this an acceptable/typical placement of a 〜て phrase, or is my interpretation simply off the mark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence sounds quite natural. I'm not really sure about why you're confused, so I'll just break down the sentence into the basic parts. First, the basic sentence here is:

> 新しい技術を、いろいろな会社が考えています。
> A lot of companies are thinking about new ways/techniques.

This clause:

> 映像を使って人が集まらないようにする 
> Use videos so that people do not gather.

is describing what comes after it, which in this case is 技術. So when you put these together, you get:

> 映像を使って人が集まらないようにする新しい技術を、いろいろな会社が考えています 
> A lot of companies are thinking about ways (of using videos so that people do not gather).

The part of the sentence in parenthesis is the relative clause describing 技術. This is the second dependent clause in the sentence:

> 新しいコロナウイルスがうつらないように 
> So that the coronavirus does not spread.

You can also add this to the basic sentence, which you get:

> 新しいコロナウイルスがうつらないように、（新しい技術を、）いろいろな会社が考えています。
>
>  A lot of companies are thinking (about new techniques) so that the coronavirus does not spread.

Here, the ように is describing 考えています. The companies are thinking *so that the coronavirus does not spread.* You can then put all these clauses together to again get the full sentence.

> 新しいコロナウイルスがうつらないように、映像を使って人が集まらないようにする新しい技術を、いろいろな会社が考えています。 
> So that the coronavirus doesn't spread, a lot of companies are thinking of new techniques that use videos.

I hope this helps. The first ように and second ように are not related. 使って is just part of the clause that is created by the  second ように.

Comment: I had been operating under the impression that ように。。。ようにする functioned similar to たり。。。たりする, which I now see was incorrect. When looking at the meaning of the two clauses separately, it becomes clear. Thanks!